# Python Inheritance and super()

Tags: python, inheritance, init, super

Why does calling Parent classes with super() does not work while using 'direct' call works fine?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print("Inside A __init__. x = %s" % self.x)
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        print("Inside B __init__. y = %s" % self.y)
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, z):
        super(C, self).__init__(6)
        super(C, self).__init__(5)
        #1.    A.__init__(self,6)
        #2.    B.__init__(self,5)
        self.z = z
        print("Inside C __init__. z = %s" % self.z)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log = C(2)
```

With uncommented 'super' the result I am getting is:

```
Inside A __init__. x = 6
Inside A __init__. x = 5
Inside C __init__. z = 2
```

so the code for 'B' class **init** is never called. But after using the commented lines '#1', and '#2' the code works as it should:

```
Inside A __init__. x = 6
Inside B __init__. y = 5
Inside C __init__. z = 2
```

Questions:

1. What is the cause of this strange 'super()' behaviour.
2. Can super() call the **init** in 'B'?
3. Is there any other way of calling all '**init**'s from Parent classes?

Comment: it's classic: "Raymond Hettinger - Super considered super! ", https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: TL;DR: `super` is not a drop-in replacement for accessing a specific parent class. Its use must be coordinated among all the classes involved.

Comment: For those who don't like video, here's the original source material: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 3):

An answer, which should rather be considered an example of how `super` works rather than how to actually write code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print("Inside A __init__. x = %s" % self.x)
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        print("Inside B __init__. y = %s" % self.y)
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, z):
        super(C, self).__init__(6)
        super(A, self).__init__(5)
        self.z = z
        print("Inside C __init__. z = %s" % self.z)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log = C(2)
```

Each class has a *method resolution order* (MRO), which is used when looking up inherited functions. For `C`, that order is

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
```

`super(foo, bar)` provides a reference to (really, a proxy for) the next class after `foo` in the MRO of `type(bar)`. `super(C, self)` provides a reference (really, a proxy) to `A`, so that `A.__init__` is the resulting call. `super(A, self)`, however, provides a proxy to `B`, resulting in a call to `B.__init__`.

The general rule, though, is that you really don't know *what* method will be called next, since you don't necessarily know the type of `self` (it could be a instance of a descendent class with a different MRO than an instance of `C`). To use `super` properly, you need to ensure that *all* potential classes are using it, so that methods will always be dispatched properly.

Comment: you can add `mro()` for each example, i guess it may be helpful.